# Devbridge autocomplete shows all suggestions

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I tried to use this autocomplete script https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/.

My code:

```
var options = {
    serviceUrl: '/GetTips',
    minChars: 1,
    autoSelectFirst: true,
    onSearchStart: function(query) {},
    onSearchComplete: function(query, suggestions) {
        console.log(query + " " + suggestions[0])
    }

};

$('#keyword').autocomplete(options);
```

This always show all suggests available from `serviceUrl`. Even if I input something which does not occur there.

Comment: using lookup (locally json) everything works great, but i need ajax version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON from serviceUrl should return only values that need to be displayed. It should be used when you have large data sets.